# EWS Performance in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS in my winforms application to create a new appointment in my Outlook (+ to get items from my Outlook Calendar).

The issue i'm having is the following:

Everything works perfect but currently it takes 20-25 seconds to retrieve my appointments (= calendar items in Outlook) and 13-20 seconds to create an appointment

The code that does this comes straight from 'Google':

```
 private void btn_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            try
            {
            service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail", "pass");
                /*service.TraceEnabled = true;
                service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;*/
                service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
                service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            }
            catch (Exception ml2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ml2.ToString());
            }

        // We get 10 items in the calendar for the next week
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
            const int NUM_APPTS = 10;
            // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
            CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
            // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
            CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);
            // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
            cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);
            // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe first " + NUM_APPTS + " appointments on your calendar from " + startDate.Date.ToShortDateString() +
                              " to " + endDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + " are: \n");

            foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
            {
                Console.Write("Subject: " + a.Subject.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("Start: " + a.Start.ToString() + " ");
                Console.Write("End: " + a.End.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

       DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
           MessageBox.Show( "Seconds: " + (d2 - d1).TotalSeconds.ToString());
        }
```

Since I have absolutely 0 experience with EWS (or developing while using API's) I was wondering if there was room for performance or I wanted to know if this is just normal? I haven't found anything EWS = SLOW related so I was worrying a bit.

Could it be that my code is wrong or that i need to configure one thing or another server sided to improve results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing to slow down you code is

```
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

You do an AutoDiscover and then set the link manually which is make the first AutoDiscover Call redundant. Auto-discover will do multiple searches of Local AD domain, DNS records to try and discover the correct URL to use so I would suggest if you are going to hardcode the URL you remark out the first line.

Also your testing logic only looks at the total time to execute you function which isn't going to be helpfully you should look at the time to complete each operation eg

```
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
```

or

```
CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
```

or any Save, Send type method call when the actually call to the server is made if you time this that will give you a true indication of the speed of each call.